# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, metar, canada, meteorology

Does anybody know what the icon inside the circle mean ?

[image]

Found at [aviationweather.gov](https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar)

Comment: Where does this image appear?

Comment: Looks like Duffy Duck.

Comment: Perhaps it means: it's bloody cold, bring a balaclava.

Comment: https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar it is where i found the image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be the symbol "M" for "missing cloud information". Note that CWIJ has a circle for cloud coverage that is slightly bigger than the standard circle size used for most other airports.

Southeast of CWIJ, there is CWIC which has the symbol M as well, but there the edge of the circle coincides with the lower part of the symbol shown in the CWIJ circle.

[image: Weather map showing CWIJ symbol]  [image: Weather map showing CWJC symbol]

[image]

Another example can be found with CXDK (normal size circle) and CXLL (big circle size)
[image: Weather map with CXDK and CXLL symbols]

There is another station towards the east (CYBK) that has a bigger circle as well, and it has a 6/8 cloud coverage symbol that does not fully fill the circle. For comparison, PAUM has a standard circle size with the same 6/8 cloud coverage symbol filling all the way to the circle's edge.

[image: CYBK 6/8 cloud coverage]  [image: PAUM 6/8 cloud coverage]

This leads me to believe that the software behind [aviationweather.gov](https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar) has a symbol library which includes cloud coverage symbols designed for a certain standard circle size. Some airport are represent by a circle which is bigger than the standard, and this leads to the strange representation of the symbol 'M' seen at CWIJ.